# Unable to add text on header of website

Tags: css, html

I am unable to add some text on the right side of header. I have place some small sized images on the right side of header and placed the little bit downwards and i want to write some text above them but i am unable to write.

I want to do like this:

[image: I want to do like this]
padding or margin problem?
[image: padding or margin problem]

```
<body>    
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><b style="font-size:20px; float: right">'RAASHFC' to 56161</b>
    <a href="#Raas"><img src="img/Raas.png" class="logo"></img></a>
    <a href="#insta"><img src="img/insta.png" class="social"></img></a>
    <a href="#tw"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="social"></img></a>
    <a href="#fb"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="social"></img></a>
</div>
```

.css source

```
.social {
 float: right;
 width: 50px;
 height: 25px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 75px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Pls help me.

Comment: put anchor tag inside the div. and create the fiddle for us

Comment: I have linked a new image, have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 .header > B
 {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 20px;
 }
 .social {
    position: absolute; 
    right:0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
          <a href="#Raas"><img src="img/Raas.png" class="logo"></img></a>
          <div class="social">
             <b>'RAASHFC' to 56161</b>
             <div>
             <a href="#insta"><img src="img/insta.png"></img></a>
             <a href="#tw"><img src="img/twitter.png"></img></a>
             <a href="#fb"><img src="img/facebook.png"></img></a>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have linked a new image. Have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your images to float:right, but not their containing element (the anchor tag). Try moving your "social" class into the anchor tags (or better still, crest a containing element for all of these anchors and add it to that) instead.

Comment: i have linked a new image, have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I have attached three kinds of snippet check what you need

```css
.social {
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
  }

#icons{
float:right;
 }
```

```html
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#Raas"><img src="img/Raas.png" class="logo"></a>
       <b style="font-size:20px; float: right">'RAASHFC' to 56161</b>
       </div>
      <div id="icons">
      <a href="#insta"><img src="img/insta.png" class="social"></a>
      <a href="#tw"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="social"></a>
      <a href="#fb"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="social"></a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

```css
    .social {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
      }
    #icons{
         float:right;
     }
#insta,#fb,#twit{
display:inline-block;
}
label{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
     <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#Raas"><img src="img/Raas.png" class="logo"style="float: left"></a>
           <b style="font-size:20px; float: right">'RAASHFC' to 56161</b>
           </div>
      <br/>
     
               
      <br/>
      <div id="icons">
          <div id="insta">
               <label>Instagram</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="https://5a5a57ff32a328601212-ee0df397c56b146e91fe14be42fa361d.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon/instagram_logos_glyph/03H5cHNMt-Jni4pe9u+7/glyph-logo_May2016_200.png" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        <div id="fb">
               <label>Facebook</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/256x256/icontexto-inside-facebook.png" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        <div id="twit">
               <label>Twitter</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/1/11/Twitter_bird_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20111228065136" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```css
.social {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
      }
    #icons{
         float:right;
      margin-right:30%;
     }
#insta,#fb,#twit{
display:inline-block;
}
label{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#Raas"><img src="img/Raas.png" class="logo"style="float: left"></a>
           <b style="font-size:20px; float: right">'RAASHFC' to 56161</b>
           </div>
      <br/>
     
               
      <br/>
      <div id="icons">
          <div id="insta">
               <label>Instagram</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="https://5a5a57ff32a328601212-ee0df397c56b146e91fe14be42fa361d.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon/instagram_logos_glyph/03H5cHNMt-Jni4pe9u+7/glyph-logo_May2016_200.png" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        <div id="fb">
               <label>Facebook</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/256x256/icontexto-inside-facebook.png" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        <div id="twit">
               <label>Twitter</label><br/>
                <a href="#insta"><img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/1/11/Twitter_bird_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20111228065136" class="social"></a>
                    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I have linked a new image, have a look at it

Comment: do you want to add the content on the top of 3 images, 
what should be the alignment of the image fully right? or as mentioned in the image

Comment: I have attached check are you expecting like this

Comment: I wanna thanks all of u
u all tried to help me and i respect that
Thanks    @Pezhvak